# Batch file to rename newest CSV and delete the rest

Tags: csv, batch-file, rename

I keep getting files transfered to a folder via sFTP. The files are in `.csv` format.

I am looking for the code for a batch file which I plan to run on a schedule that will do the following in sequence:

- Delete the file named `extract.csv` if it exists.
- Rename the most recent `.csv` file to `extract.csv`.
- Delete all other files that start with `SL`.

Comment: What code have you got so far for this? (If you have none, take a look at [Jeff Atwood's question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/49614/delete-files-older-than-x-days) to get you started.)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
CD "put_path_to_ftp_folder_here"

IF EXIST extract.csv DEL extract.csv
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR "*.csv" /B /O:-D') DO REN %%G extract.csv
DEL SL*
```

Bare in mind `DEL` is case-insensitive!

Also, this is not a script writing service. Maybe read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) *"again"*...